# How to chmod all folders recursively excluding all folders within a specific folder?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, find, chmod

I would like to `chmod` all folders and subfolders within a specific folder, except I wish to exclude one folder (and all subfolders it contains).

What I have so far is a hack of the following solutions from StackOverflow:

- [How to set chmod for a folder and all of its subfolders and files in Linux Ubuntu Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11512211/3504007)
- [Exclude directory from find . command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4210072/3504007)

Here is what I came up with so far:

```
find . -type d \( -path ./node_modules \) -prune -o -print -exec chmod 644 {}\;
```

The problem is with or without `-print` I receive the following error :

> find: missing argument to `-exec'

The following line has the expected results I need `-exec chmod 644{}\;` to read from:

```
find . -type d \( -path ./node_modules \) -prune -o -print
```

What am I missing on that line to pipe the data to `-exec` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `-print`, escape `( and )` and add space after `{}`

```
find . -type d \( -path ./node_modules \) -prune -o -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: Your solution worked.  Thank you.  I was in the middle of writing my solution when you posted this.  Accepting as solution and upvoted.

Answer (score 7):

After some playing around, I found that the following worked for me:

`chmod` all files recursively excluding files:

```
find . -not -path "*/node_modules*" -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

`chmod` all folders recursively excluding folder:

```
find . -not -path "*/node_modules*" -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

chmod  all folders  recursively
find /opt/git/  -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +

chmod all files recursively
find /opt/git/  -type f -exec chmod 755 {} +

Luiz Marinho

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://superuser.com/help/formatting).